# Clone an instantiated object with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, object

Couldn't find an answer dealing with cloning instantiated objects in JavaScript. What's the best way to clone an existing instantiated object? E.g.,

```
function Person() {
}

Person.prototype.setName = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var person = new Person();
person.setName('Charles Xavier');

function cloneInstantiated(instantiatedObject) {
    var clone = ... new Person ... ????

    return clone;
}

var clone = cloneInstantiated(person);

console.log(clone.name); // Charles Xavier

if(clone !== person) {
    console.log('Success! We have cloned Charles Xavier into a different memory address.');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to clone an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: @svidgen There's a big difference between `Object` and *instantiated object*!

Comment: @TomášZato *All* objects are "instantiated." If the concern is that the prototype is absent from the new object after using one of the widely used `clone()` functions, just add the prototype to the new object after the basic `clone()`. If the OP's concern is that his clone-method-of-choice doesn't also copy instance methods ... it's simple enough to loop and/or recurse through and add them.

Comment: Often it's quite important that `clone instanceof Person` returns `true`. I don't see a point in "adding the prototype later" if you can *instantiate* object using `new` and then copy properties.

Comment: is o2=Object.create(o) enough for your app?

Answer (score 2):

There's no native or universal way as far as I know. I prefer to write `.clone` method for my pseudo classes and use it:

```
Person.prototype.clone = function() {
    var clone = new Person()
    clone.name = this.name;
}
```

You could loop through own properties of the object to clone them while not copying stuff inherited from other objects:

```
for(var i in this) {
   if(this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       clone[i] = this[i];
   }
}
```

This will copy everything that was added to your object after instantiating (eg. won't copy the prototype properties which were already added by calling `new Person`.

#### [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf#Browser_compatibility)

<sup>[thanks to Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388077/clone-an-instantiated-object-with-javascript/27388300?noredirect=1#comment43265945_27388300)</sup>
This method allows you to retrieve the prototype of any object. So instead of `new Name` you can use:

```
var clone = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))
```

That's an universal solution which can save you lot of work. You must then proceed with copying own properties using `for(var i in ...)`.

#### `Object.create` ([supported since node V8](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/ecma-5mozilla-features-implemented-in-v8)) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create))

Finally, you could create a person that inherits from the original object:

```
var clone = Object.create(this);
```

That can be useful in special cases, but normally I wouldn't recommend it.

#### `.toSource` ([Node.js module](https://nodejsmodules.org/pkg/tosource)) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource))

It's also interesting to know that you can (<del>in certain browsers</del> firefox only) override method `.toSource` which is defined for all objects, even the native ones:

[image: toSource method]

In certain cases, you might want to do:

```
Person.prototype.toSource = function() {
    //Assuming name can be given in constructor
    return "new Person("+this.name.toSource()+")";
}
```

#### Further reading

Aside from the linked docs, I found this nice article about javascript object inheritance:

- [Prototypal Inheritance - How To Node - NodeJS](http://howtonode.org/prototypical-inheritance)

Comment: I'd recomment to use `var clone = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))`

Comment: If you get the prototype you don't copy the objects own properties. However your's is a good way to create object of the same instance without typing the name directly. +1 :)

Comment: I thought that was the initalisation code for the loop over the own properties in the snippet right above?

Comment: Yeah. As I say, your's a good idea. I just wasn't sure you realise that loop is still necesary. I'll try to add your idea to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Kirk Wasn't my answer sufficient? I've spent a lot of time with it and now it seems you didn't even read it.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjh0g0Ls/)

```
function Person() {
}

Person.prototype.setName = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var person = new Person();
person.setName('Charles Xavier');

function cloneInstantiated(instantiatedObject) {
    var clone = {};
    for (key in instantiatedObject) {
        clone[key] = instantiatedObject[key];
    }
    return clone;
}

var clone = cloneInstantiated(person);

console.log(clone.name); // Charles Xavier

if(clone !== person) {
    console.log('Success! We have cloned Charles Xavier into a different memory address.');
}
```

Comment: You've got uninitialised global variable in your code (`key`). Looping through all keys is really not necessary, usually you just need to copy the topmost layer of inheritance.

Comment: What if one of the variables on the instance had captured a reference to the other object, or if a function was explicitly bound for instance? While it works for this specific case, this doesn't work as a generic solution.